# How do I remove a directory and all its contents?

Tags: bash, rm

In bash all I know is that

```
rmdir directoryname
```

will remove the directory but only if it's empty. Is there a way to force remove subdirectories?

Answer (score 335, accepted):

The following command will do it for you. Use caution though if this isn't your intention as this also removes files in the directory and subdirectories.

```
rm -rf directoryname
```

Comment: "-f" is "--force" which overrides some sanity checks and prompting.  A safer command to start with would be `rm -r directoryname`.

Comment: For some reason I get a `rm: invalid option -- r` error when trying to delete a directory with rm -r <directoryname>.

Comment: @Sunspawn [Check this related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/37823/how-to-delete-file-with-option-character-in-name-in-linux) to see if that's the case.

Comment: @JimParis I think the word "safer" is relative. Suppose you are writing a script to run on a remote computer. That script has a command which is supposed to remove a directory. Here, it would be "safer" to use `rm -rf directoryname` coz you wouldn't want your script to pause execution, because it's waiting for user input. Of course, you have to be sure that deleting the directory would do no harm.

Comment: Note that this will also delete files (as opposed to subdirectories).

Answer (score 9):

if `rm -rf directoryname` fails you, try using `rm -R -f directoryname`, or `rm --recursive -f directoryname`.

If you are not having any luck with these, you should consider reinstalling rm or switching shells.

Comment: These were the options available on my rm man page, I looked it up by typing `man rm` to view my options on recursive deletion and the _force_ options.

Comment: Does your `rm` man page list `-r`?  What does it do?  (Try it in a directory that you create just for testing purposes, with only dummy files (and maybe subdirectories) in it.)  What operating system are you using?

Comment: P.S. If `rm -r` doesn't work, that would be an OS issue, not a shell issue. (Strictly speaking, it would be an issue with the version of `rm` that you're using, so you could address it by installing a different version of `rm`, or searching your system to see whether you already have a different version of `rm` in some directory other than `/bin`.)

Comment: Ah, right. I forgot to mention I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 When I ran `man rm` in my terminal, it gave me a text file with the `less` text viewer. I scrolled found an indented entry with a whole that had the _-R_ and _--recursive_ options cozied up with the _-r_ option, signifying that all of those arguments are identical.

Comment: *edit: have you tried `sudo rm -r directoryName`*?

The unwritten rules of the basic commands is that `-r` will allow a program to run recursively on every file your filesystem (starting where ever you choose!) and that -f will forcefully do things, even if it's _dangerous_. 'cd', 'mv', 'ls' _mostly_ holds this principle true. `ls -r /` is gonna be a duzie, and `cp -rf / /dev/null` will destroy everything on your filesystem. <--Never run that command!

Comment: What would make `rm -Rf dir` succeed when `rm -rf dir` fails? On GNU systems, and other systems where the non-standard `-R` option is implemented, `-r` and `-R` (and `--recursive`) are the one and same option.

Answer (score 5):

Other answers show how to completely remove a directory’s content, but IMO they don’t address the *literal* question of the original post — that is, *how can one delete **subdirectories** (as opposed to usual files)*.  In other words, how can one delete empty directory structures **while keeping subdirectories containing files** ?

This can be achieved with `find` :

```
find directoryname -type d -delete
```

This command will recursively search for directories (`-type d`) through `directoryname` and `-delete` them *only* if their subdirectories or themselves don’t contain any files.